# How To Have The Same Sprite In Multiple Locations Cocos2d

Tags: cocos2d-iphone, sprite

How To Have The Same Sprite In Multiple Locations Cocos2d Please Help
I have searched all over and cannot find answer

Answer (score 1):

Just create multiple Sprites (CCSprite instances). They can all use the same texture (bitmap-file).

```
CCSprite * mySprite1;
CCSprite * mySprite2;
CCSprite * mySprite3;

// create several sprites from the same bitmap file
mySprite1 = [CCSprite spriteWithFile:@"spriteBitmap.png"];
mySprite2 = [CCSprite spriteWithFile:@"spriteBitmap.png"];
mySprite3 = [CCSprite spriteWithFile:@"spriteBitmap.png"];

mySprite1.position = ccp(100, 100);
mySprite2.position = ccp(200, 200);
mySprite3.position = ccp(300, 300);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can not add the same CCSprite as a child to multiple CCNodes but you can make Cocos2D render the same CCSprite multiple times.
To achieve this you need to create a subclass of CCNode that will store the reference to your CCSprite and draw it in its -draw method applying required transformations.
For example

```
-(void)draw
{
    [super draw];

    CGPoint initialPosition = [_node position];
    float initialScale = [_node scale];

    [_node setScale:self.scale];
    [_node setPosition:self.position];
    [_node visit];
    [_node setPosition:initialPosition];
    [_node setScale:initialScale];
}
```

You may have to to use glScissor if you need picture-in-picture appearance.

Then you just need to addChild an instance of this class for every time you want an additional copy of your original CCSprite rendered.

Answer (score 0):

Put a method on a for loop.

Inside the method create the CCSprite and modify it.

This is best suited for static sprites, since I don't know how you would access these outside of the method.